# Nested loop not printing the first element but going to 2nd element?

Tags: python

I have a very simple piece of code but it's driving me nuts to understand the logic.

```
for a in range(6):
   print("\t\t")
for j in range(a):
    print(a, end=" ")
```

The output is:

```
1       
2 2         
3 3 3       
4 4 4 4         
5 5 5 5 5
```

the first value to be printed is supposed to be 0 since the range(6) starts from 0 and a and j wrapped in for loops both are supposedly getting 0 as first element but it starts from 1 instead.

Comment: `range(0)` is equivalent to an empty list

Comment: `list(range(0))` is nothing, so the nested for loop does nothing.

Comment: Your code does not produce the output given. I guess your indentation is off.

Comment: you didn't indent your second loop. Second loop run after the entire first loop. So second loop run with a = 5 only (the last value stored by the first loop to a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `a` is the number of iterations of the inner loop.  (Note that the question should have the `j` loop indented, so that it is inside the `a` loop, in order to get the output shown.)

On the first iteration, `a` is `0`, and then `range(0)` will give an empty sequence, which give zero iterations when iterating over it.  (Specifically a `StopIteration` will occur the first time a value is fetched.)

On the next iteration of the outer loop, there will be one `j` value when iterating, and so forth.

So 0 is printed 0 times (i.e. not at all), then 1 is printed once, 2 is printed twice, ... , 5 is printed 5 times.

You are not using the values of `j` at all, but they will be:

- when `a` is 0: no iterations
- when `a` is 1: `j` is 0 only
- when `a` is 2: `j` is 0, 1
- ... etc, up to ...
- when `a` is 6: `j` is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Note that in fact it is conventional to use a variable name `_` for a loop variable whose value you do not use (at least assuming that it not inside a loop already using `_`).  If you adhere to this convention (i.e. use `_` instead of `j`) and also fix the indentation, then your code might look like:

```
for a in range(6):
    print("\t\t")
    for _ in range(a):
        print(a, end=" ")
```

Comment: how about the below code:

for i in range(11):
    print("\t\t")
    for j in range(11):
        print(i * j, end=" ")

it prints 0 to start with.

Comment: @Natan That is because the `j` loop is now over `range(11)` rather than `range(i)`, so it always has 11 iterations, whatever the value of `i`. Note in any case that the first `j` value will *also* be 0, so you will of course see a 0 whenever either `i` or `j` is equal to 0.

Answer (score 2):

That comes, because the `for loop` in `range 0` will not be executed. You can not execute something if that has to go 0 times. To make it run as you would like to be, you would have to write following code:

```
for a in range(6):
   print("\t\t")
   for j in range(a + 1):
       print(a, end=" ")
```